# What is the Equivalent method in UWP for the CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo() method?

Tags: c#, uwp

What is the Equivalent method in UWP for the **CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()** method. which method available in system.globalization.Culture info class in the WPF.

Comment: Windows.Globalization namespace.  Google "winrt getcultureinfo" for existing Q+A about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, and also you can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to get the UI culture which is related to app localization.